# training of a fully convolutional network with images of arbitrary size

Tags: python, tensorflow, variables, keras

I have built a fully convolutional network that I feed subnetwork A with MFCC coefficients
The wav files where MFCCs are calculated from have variable duration, so every wav ends up to a list of MFCCs with variable length.
I made an implementation and try to feed the sub network A with batch size=1.

```
    X_audio_images = loadFeaturesFromFiles(trainFilenames, params)

from sklearn.model_selection import KFold
n_split=5
f=0
all_acc=[]
for train_index,test_index in KFold(n_split).split(X):
    f=f+1
    print('\n\n\nFold ',f,' of ', n_split)
    for k, l in zip(train_index, test_index):
        xA_train,xA_test=X_audio_images[k],X_audio_images[l]
        xB_train,xB_test=X[k],X[l]
        y_train,y_test=y[k],y[l]
    
    
    xA_test = np.array(xA_test)
    xA_test = np.expand_dims(xA_test, axis=(0, 3))
    xA_train = np.array(xA_train)
    xA_train = np.expand_dims(xA_train, axis=(0, 3))
    xB_test = np.expand_dims(xB_test, axis=(0))
    xB_train = np.expand_dims(xB_train, axis=(0))
    y_train = np.expand_dims(y_train, axis=(0))
    y_test = np.expand_dims(y_test, axis=(0))
     
    inputsA = Input(shape=(None, None, 1))

    xA = Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=5, strides=1)(inputsA)
    xA = Dropout(0.5)(xA)
    xA = BatchNormalization()(xA)
    xA = Activation('relu')(xA)

    xA = MaxPooling2D()(xA)

    xA = Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=5, strides=1)(xA)
    xA = Dropout(0.5)(xA)
    xA = BatchNormalization()(xA)
    xA = Activation('relu')(xA)

    xA = MaxPooling2D()(xA)

    xA = Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=1, strides=1)(xA)
    xA = Dropout(0.3)(xA)
    xA = BatchNormalization()(xA)
    xA = Activation('relu')(xA)

    
    # Fully connected layer 2
    xA = Conv2D(filters=4, kernel_size=1, strides=1)(xA)
    xA = Dropout(0.2)(xA)
    xA = BatchNormalization()(xA)
    xA = GlobalMaxPooling2D()(xA)
   # predictions = tf.keras.layers.Activation('softmax')(x)
    
    inputsB = Input(shape=(input_dim,))
    xB = Dense(128, activation='relu')(inputsB)
    xB = Dropout(0.5)(xB)
    xB = Dense(128, activation='relu')(xB)
    xB = Dropout(0.5)(xB)

    combined =Concatenate()([xA, xB])
    out = Dense(104,  activation='relu')(combined)
    out = Dropout(0.3)(out)
    out = Dense(4,  activation='softmax')(out)


    model = Model(inputs=[inputsA, inputsB], outputs=out)
    model.summary()
    
   
 
    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=Adam(learning_rate=0.01),metrics= ['accuracy'])
    
    # Train the model.
    print(xA_train.shape, xB_train.shape)
    model.fit( [xA_train, xB_train], y_train,  epochs=500,   batch_size=12, validation_data=([xA_test, xB_test], y_test), callbacks=[es] )
    loss,acc = model.evaluate( [xA_test, xB_test],  y_test)
    
    print('\nModel evaluation for fold ',f,' accuracy: ',acc,'\n\n')
    all_acc.append(acc)
#    time.sleep(2)
    

print('\n\nTest Accuracies for all folds: ', all_acc, '\tAverage: ', np.average(all_acc))
```

but I think its not actually doing what is supposed to do
What I am trying to understand is how I feed the network every time with variable input length set the network dimension and then change it all over again and actually learn something.
What is the steps for training?

Comment: Variable shape input are not supported in tensorflow layers. So, you can't do that. What you can do, however, is to use ```tf.image.resize_with_crop_or_pad``` to resize all images to same shape with some zeroed margins. Is that acceptable?

Comment: @tornikeo that is not true, you absolutely can put in variable image shape

Answer (score 0):

If you want variable input size this is how to do it, *but that won't work with Dense connections*

If you want this to work with Dense connections you'll need to provide a set input size, since this creates a relationship between the image size and how many connections are coming out of it

Also, your variable 'input_dim' isn't referenced, is that what you're wanting to vary?